babel parser cannot parse `import type` declaration
When I try to use parser.parse("import type {Element} from 'react-devtools-shared/src/frontend/types';", {sourceType: "unambiguous"}); to parse the statement, I encounter an error Unexpected token, expected "from".
Is there any problem?
Someone can help me? Thanks a lot.
I try to set errorRecovery:true and strictMode:false, but these are not helpful.

You need either the flow or typescript plugin.
parser.parse("import type {Element} from 'react-devtools-shared/src/frontend/types';", {
  sourceType: "unambiguous",
  plugins: ['typescript']
})

See it on AST Explorer for reference.

